# angularjs javascript filter error works on plunker but not in app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular js app which has the following controller:

```
app.controller('myplancontroller', function(PlannedService, $scope, $modal, $log, $http) {

    PlannedService.getPlanned(function(data){
        $scope.planneddetails = data;
        console.log(data);
    });

    $scope.unplanned = $scope.planneddetails.filter(function(item) { return (item.term === 'none');});
});
```

When i am trying to access the $scope.unplanned, it is throwing me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'filter' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/app.js:222:45)
    at invoke (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:3704:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:3715:23)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:6766:28
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:6179:34
    at forEach (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:309:20)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:6166:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:5630:15)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:5633:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.js:5633:13) angular.js:9413
(anonymous function)
```

But when i tried a similar thing on a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zfFtb09E2utPwGDKChl6?p=preview) here, it worked. What might be happening?

Comment: Does `PlannedService.getPlanned` perform something asynchronous? If so, your problem is that `$scope.planneddetails` is empty at the point where you're trying to access its data.

Comment: I assume PlannedService.getPlanned is async? Then $scope.planneddetails well most probably _is_ undefined when you try to assign to $scope.unplanned, which is exactly what the error message says, BTW at first glance I see no relation between the code above and the plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that `PlannedService.getPlanned` is performing some asynchronous task, such as an AJAX request. Assuming this is the case, `$scope.planneddetails` will not have the data you expect at the point where you're trying to access it, and this is what your error is indicated.

If you're looking set `$scope.unplanned` and then have your view update, you can move that code into the callback you're passing to `PlannedService.getPlanned`:

```
app.controller('myplancontroller', function(PlannedService, $scope, $modal, $log, $http) {

    PlannedService.getPlanned(function(data){
        $scope.planneddetails = data;
        console.log(data);
        $scope.unplanned = $scope.planneddetails.filter(function(item) { return (item.term === 'none');});
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi, i made an edit to the question. I tried your method as well and it gave me this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/jqLite/onargs

Comment: Are you sure that new error is as a result of this code and not  from something inside of a linking function on a directive (or controller if you're doing DOM stuff there)? jqLite shouldn't be involved in this.

Comment: i found the issue. here it is https://github.com/ganarajpr/angular-dragdrop/issues/9

Comment: Interesting. Not seeing how that is relevant to what you've shown here. Is the problem elsewhere in your code then?

Comment: it was in the javascript filenamed draganddrop.js which is in the plunker. It was the same file i used even in the app. :)..but your answer was also the solution for the filtering..